# CADの図形編集コマンド（MOVEなど）で選択した図形のうち特定の図形を除きたい

Tags: .net, ijcad, arx, autocad

IJCAD2020でVB.NET(.NET API)を使用して開発を行っています。
IJCADの生コマンドで選択した図形のうち特定の図形を除く処理を実装しております。

具体的には下記の関数内（Editor.PromptedForSelection置き換え）で選択セットの中から特定の図形を判定し、特定の図形を除外した新しい選択セットを取得してEditorにセットしています。

以下はサンプルコードです。

```
Private Sub Editor_PromptedForSelection(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PromptSelectionResultEventArgs)
    If Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument IsNot Nothing Then
        'Dim ed As Editor = DirectCast(sender, Editor)
        Dim ed As Editor = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor
        Dim icdSSetNew As SelectionSet = Nothing'新しい選択セット（特定の図形を除いた）
        Dim icdSSetOrg As SelectionSet = Nothing'元の選択セット
        IcadSelSet_Clear(icdSSetOrg)
        Try
            '選択された図形をEditorクラスインスタンスから取得
            Dim gcSSPrompt As PromptSelectionResult = ed.SelectImplied()
            If Not gcSSPrompt.Value Is Nothing Then
                icdSSetOrg = gcSSPrompt.Value
                Dim ssIdsNew As New ObjectIdCollection
                Using icdTrans As Transaction = icdDoc.Database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction
                    'ターゲットを選択セットから除外する
                    For Each selobj As SelectedObject In icdSSetOrg
                        Dim icdEnt As Entity = IcadTrans_GetObject(icdTrans, selobj.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead)
                        If icdEnt Is Nothing Then Continue For
                        Try
                            If＜ターゲットか?＞ Then Continue For
                            If Not ssIdsNew.Contains(icdEnt.ObjectId) Then
                                ssIdsNew.Add(icdEnt.ObjectId)
                            End If
                        Catch ex As System.Exception
                            
                        Finally
                            If Not icdEnt Is Nothing Then icdEnt.Dispose()
                        End Try
                    Next

                    'ssIdsNew→icdSSetNew(ObjectIdCollectionをSelectionSetに変換)
                      
                End Using
            End If
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            
        End Try

        '選択セットをEditorに再セット
        ed.SetImpliedSelection(icdSSetNew)

    End If                                                                                                                                      
End Sub
```

別途、Document.ImpliedSelectionChanged（事前選択セットに図形を追加したり削除されたときに通知）では同様のコーディングで特定の図形を選択から除外することができました。

何かアドバイスをいただければ幸いです。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

選択セットの置き換え方法としては、以下のイベントを使用する方法があります。
・Editor.PromptForSelectionEnding　選択操作が完了したときに発生するイベント
・Editor.SelectionAdded　　　　　　現在の選択セットにオブジェクトが追加されたときに発生するイベント

また、Selection****EventArgs.Remove()メソッドで特定の図形を除く事が可能です。

なお、Editor.SelectImplied()メソッドは事前選択が行われた状態で選択セットを取得するものです。

MOVEコマンドなどの特定の編集コマンドに限定したい場合は、
Document.CommandWillStartイベントと併用する方法が考えられます。